# SetState isn't populating an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React so this might be a silly question. I'm trying to fetch data from an API and populate it in another array. The API portion is working correctly, as I'm able to console log the data. What's not working is, using this.setState to move the data from the initialCustomerTypeList to the CustomerTypeList array. The console.log is showing an empty array on CustomerTypeList and I'm not sure why.

Code:

```
  this.state1 = {
            CustomerTypeList: [],
        };

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     
          }

    componentDidMount() {
        let initialCustomerTypeList = [];
        fetch('api/CustomerType')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
                initialCustomerTypeList = data.map((customertypeLine) => {
                    return customertypeLine
                });
                console.log("Initial Data" , initialCustomerTypeList);
                this.setState({
                   CustomerTypeList : initialCustomerTypeList
                 
                })
                console.log("CustomerTypeList" , this.state1.CustomerTypeList);
            })
```

Again initialCustomerTypeList has data, it just isn't moving it to CustomerTypeList. Also, it's in this.state1 because I already have a this.state declared holding data from the input fields.

Edit: I've also tried adding the CustomerTypeList to the original this.state (not pictured) but I get the same results.

Comment: I see 2 issues at first glance, 1) you are using `state1` instead of `state`, 2) `setState` is asynchronous so when you try to console the result of the updated state it has not yet completed the action to update, to see it updating you can try to add this cide inside the render function of your component `{console.log("CustomerTypeList" , this.state.CustomerTypeList)}` this will ensure the `console runs after the state is updated.

Comment: I did change it to state and combined that with an answer below and it seems to work now. I'm assuming you can have more then one this.state, in your react component, is that correct?

Comment: Happy it works for you, you can not have more then one `state` object per component in react (however each component has its own `state` object), but you can have multiple properties in the `state` object, like `state = {firstName: "Shmili", lastName:"Breuer", hobbies: ["gardening","fishing"]}` and when you update the state via `setState` like this `this.setState({firstName: "Shmily"})` react takes care to only update the prperty you were updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.state1 = {
            CustomerTypeList: [],
        };

this.setState({
               CustomerTypeList : initialCustomerTypeList
             
            })
            console.log("CustomerTypeList" , this.state1.CustomerTypeList);
```

to

```
this.state = {
            CustomerTypeList: [],
        };

this.setState({ CustomerTypeList : initialCustomerTypeList},
           () => console.log("CustomerTypeList" , this.state1.CustomerTypeList);
     );
```

Comment: I removed the "1" from the state1. now it just reads this.state.CustomerTypeList. But your answer worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React does state updates in batches. So you may not be able to read the state property post you call setState() as it is asynchronous in nature.

https://code.likeagirl.io/reactjs-dealing-with-asynchronous-state-updates-ff6ac4d24b05

Comment: Thanks for the link. This does a really good job explaining the state updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be that you're using `this.state1` instead of `this.state`, try to log `this.state.CustomerTypeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement needed

```
 this.state = {
   CustomerTypeList: []
 }
```

setting data

```
     componentDidMount() {
        let CustomerTypeList= [];
        fetch('api/CustomerType')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
                CustomerTypeList = data.map((customertypeLine) => {
                    return customertypeLine
                });
                this.setState({
                   CustomerTypeList
                }, ()=> console.log(this.state.CustomerTypeList))
            })
      }
```

> Don't check/console right after setting data to the state because it updates asynchronously. you can check/console as a callback of `setState()` method.